# How to get an AtKey value(AtValue) from RemoteSecondary instead of LocalSecondary(default) in at_client/at_client_mobile

Tags: flutter, dart, at-platform

I was trying to get an `AtKey` value from my Secondaries(Local by default) using [at_client](https://pub.dev/packages/at_client)/[at_client_mobile](https://pub.dev/packages/at_client_mobile). I don't have that key in my **LocalSecondary**. So I need to get it from my **RemoteSecondary**. How could I get it from **RemoteSecondary** before the sync happens?